# Is $\mathbb{N}$ totally bounded space?

Tags: metric-spaces

If we look a set $\mathbb{N}$ in metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$ is  $\mathbb{N}$ there a totally bounded space? What about looking set $\mathbb{N}$ in metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where $d$ is discrete metric?
Definition of totally bounded space:
A metric space $(M,d)$ is totally bounded if and only if for every real number $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite collection of open balls in M of radius $\epsilon$  whose union contains M.

My work
It is pretty clear that is not the case but I need to show this by using definition of totally bounded space. I first start looking $B(n,\frac{1}{2})$ ball around every natural number, but $\mathbb{N}$ is not a finite set so we don't have a finite cover of set I think that this could be a problem?

Comment: What is $(\mathbb R,d_2)$?

Comment: $d_2$ is normal Euclidian metric.

Comment: Why don't you show us your definition of a totally bounded space ?

Comment: You cannot cover $\mathbb N$ by a  finite number of open balls of raidius $\frac 1 2$ in either of the two metrics.

Comment: What is your question precisely ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust is N totally bounded space in this two metric space and why?
And I add my definition

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let any finite cover $C=\cup_{i=1}^n B(b_n,\epsilon)$. The number

$$\max_{1\le i\le n}(b_n+\epsilon)$$ is an upper bound to the integers contained in $C$ and cannot contain

$$\left\lceil\max_{1\le i\le n}(b_n+\epsilon)\right\rceil+1.$$

---

In simpler and more general terms, an open ball is bounded above and so is a finite union of balls. Hence there is a natural larger than the upper bound, which is not covered.

Comment: This is for discrete and $d_2$?

Comment: @josf: what tells you that this is for "discrete" ?

Comment: I don't know, but you in all proof never use diameter so I thnk that this could be use for both metrics

Comment: @josf: ponder why I use $p_n+r_r$. (By the way, changing to $\epsilon$).